# Included files after list not rendered correctly

Tags: textmate2, asciidoc

main.asc:

```
== Items
include::foo.asc[]
include::bar.asc[]
```

foo.asc

```
=== Foo Title
==== List of things
* thing one
* thing two
```

bar.asc

```
=== Bar Title
this is a summary of bar
```

When `main.asc` is rendered, the following text is displayed:

## Items

### Foo Title

- thing one
- thing two === Bar Title

this is a summary of bar

I've also tried adding a simple paragraph at end of `foo.asc` after the list to see if that will fix the problem--it didn't.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a line between the two include statements seems to fix the issue:

```
== Items
include::foo.asc[]

include::bar.asc[]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should always end all asciidoc files with a blank line, I actually keep a comment at the end of all my files to remember me:

```
////
Always end a file with a blank line to avoid include problems.
////
```

When you don't have a blank line the second file is included at end of previews line, and the result will be:

```
thing two === Bar Title
```